# Execute Jar file as standalone application

Tags: java, maven, javafx, maven-3

I want to execute jar file as standalone application. When I run the below command I get this error message:

```
[rcbandit@Laptop target]$ /opt/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -jar DX57DC-1.0.jar
no main manifest attribute, in DX57DC-1.0.jar
[rcbandit@Laptop target]$
```

This is the POM configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.dx57dc</groupId>
    <artifactId>DX57DC</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DX57DC</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <mainClass></mainClass>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>Corporation Name</name>
    </organization>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludeScope>system</excludeScope>
                            <excludeGroupIds>junit,org.mockito,org.hamcrest</excludeGroupIds>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.dx57dc.main.DX57DC</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I suppose that I'm missing a maven plugin. Can you tell me how I can fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an executable jar with dependencies using Maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for a JAR file to be [executable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html) it needs to have a manifest file with `Main-Class` and `Class-Path` entries:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>my.package.App</mainClass>               
                    </manifest>           
                </archive>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-package</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

This produces a `MANIFEST.MF` file under `META-INF` directory in the root of your jar file. Only relevant entries listed:

```
Class-Path: lib/somejar.jar
Main-Class: my.package.App
```

The `Class-Path` states that in the directory where the jar file resides there exists a `lib` folder with file `somejar.jar` in it.

The `Main-Class` states that the file `App.class` exists in package  `my.package` and  its `main` method will be run.

#### update

If the `lib` folder isn't present the execution will fail when first dependent class is to be loaded. To evade this you can [pack all the dependencies in your jar with the shade](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html) plugin:

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>my.package.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Since all the dependencies are packed together the `Class-Path` entry is not necessary any more.

Answer (score 2):

Your jar doesn't contain a Manifest that specifies the executable main() function, so java doesn't know which class to execute/start.

When using maven, have a look at the assembly plugin. This enables you to create a jar with the correct Manifest.

Or simply start your programm with: `java -cp DX57DC-1.0.jar 'your_main_class_here'`

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 2):

Create your jar as follows:

- Open Command Prompt or Terminal and locate the directory where all Classes are stored
- Type following command:

  `jar cfev YourJarName.jar EntryClass *`

Or, If Your classes are in some package then,

- Go Outside Your Package Folder and run the following command:

  `jar cfev YourJarName.jar YourPackage.EntryClass YourPackage/*`

This will create a jar file.
Now if Double Clicking does not open the jar then,

- Locate the Directory in the Terminal or Cmd, where the jar file is kept, and run the following command:

  `java -jar YourJarName.jar args`

Here Options were:

```
    -c  create new archive
    -f  specify archive file name
    -e  specify application entry point for stand-alone application
        bundled into an executable jar file
    -v  generate verbose output on standard output
```

Hope this will Help.

Answer (score 1):

try adding something like this to plugins:

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>attached</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>com.package.to.my.Main</mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Which plugin will be more suitable?  maven-assembly-plugin or the maven-jar-plugin

Comment: We've been using the assembly plugin, I haven't tried the jar plugin, but maybe that's the way to go.

Comment: With the assembly plugin there are two jar files generated. How I can generate just one?

Comment: Should only be one, are you sure you removed the jar plugin? What command are you using to build?

Comment: I pasted the the POM file at the beginning.

Comment: If you only have either the jar or the assembly plugin, I'm not sure how there could be two. But regarding which is more appropriate, assembly plugin is geared for building an uber jar (containing all dependent jars in addition to your classes). Both jar and assembly plugin seem to require the shade plugin beyond if you require more than "basic" support.  http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/